# getting error in using the having and group by clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

hHis is my table dummy:

```
OUTPUT  OQTY    INPUT   IQTY    EN      FLEX
Y3      1       X       2       Y       0
Y4      1       X       2       Y       0
Y5      1       X       2       N       0
Y6      1       X       2       N       0
Y1      1       X       2       Y       0
Y2      1       X       2       Y       0
```

And my query is:

```
SELECT INPUT,count(*)
FROM dummy
GROUP BY INPUT
HAVING EN = 'Y';
```

I am getting an error not a group by statement.

I want a count of similar inputs with en = Y.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use `having` here, it's generally for checking conditions that can only be calculated *after* grouping is done (like `having count(*) > 2` or similar).

Use something like:

```
select    input,
          count(*) as quantity
from      dummy
where     en = 'Y'
group by  input
```

The reason you *can't* use `having en = 'Y'` is because you've already loaded up all the rows and grouped them before the `having` clause kicks in. In other words, you no longer *have* the `en` column information, it's been lost in the aggregation.

---

See transcript below:

```
>  DROP TABLE DUMMY%
>  CREATE TABLE DUMMY (OUTPUT CHAR(2), OQTY INTEGER,
>>    INPUT CHAR(1), IQTY INTEGER, EN CHAR(2), FLEX INTEGER)%
>  INSERT INTO DUMMY (OUTPUT, OQTY, INPUT, IQTY, EN, FLEX) VALUES
>>    ('Y3',1,'X',2,'Y',0), ('Y4',1,'X',2,'Y',0), ('Y5',1,'X',2,'N',0), 
>>    ('Y6',1,'X',2,'N',0), ('Y1',1,'X',2,'Y',0), ('Y2',1,'X',2,'Y',0)%

>  SELECT * FROM DUMMY ORDER BY EN, INPUT, OUTPUT%
   OUTPUT  OQTY  INPUT  IQTY  EN  FLEX
   ------  ----  -----  ----  --  ----
   Y5         1  X         2  N      0
   Y6         1  X         2  N      0
   Y1         1  X         2  Y      0
   Y2         1  X         2  Y      0
   Y3         1  X         2  Y      0
   Y4         1  X         2  Y      0

>  SELECT      INPUT, COUNT(*) AS QUANT
>>    FROM     DUMMY
>>    WHERE    EN = 'Y'
>>    GROUP BY INPUT%
   INPUT  QUANT
   -----  -----
   X          4
```

And, updating one of the relevant rows:

```
>  UPDATE DUMMY SET INPUT = 'Z' WHERE OUTPUT = 'Y1'%   
>  SELECT * FROM DUMMY ORDER BY EN, INPUT, OUTPUT%
   OUTPUT  OQTY  INPUT  IQTY  EN  FLEX
   ------  ----  -----  ----  --  ----
   Y5         1  X         2  N      0
   Y6         1  X         2  N      0
   Y2         1  X         2  Y      0
   Y3         1  X         2  Y      0
   Y4         1  X         2  Y      0
   Y1         1  Z         2  Y      0

>  SELECT      INPUT, COUNT(*) AS QUANT
>>    FROM     DUMMY
>>    WHERE    EN = 'Y'
>>    GROUP BY INPUT%
   INPUT  QUANT
   -----  -----
   X          3
   Z          1
```

Comment: No it will give output as X 1 
but the desired one is X 4

Comment: Did you run exactly @paxdiablo 's query and got different results?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Count(*), define the column name which get to be counted.

check below

```
SELECT INPUT,count(EN) As TotalEnCount
FROM [dummy]
where EN = 'Y'
GROUP BY INPUT
```